# Is there a operation to remove rows that contain years (multiple filtering)?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have crash data that looks like so but with a few more other variables and on a much larger scale.

| Object ID | crashYear |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018 |
| 2 | 2019 |
| 3 | 2020 |
| 4 | 2021 |
| 5 | 2003 |
| 6 | 2006 |
| 7 | 2008 |
| 8 | 2002 |

I want to to only keep crashes that occurred in 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 and remove the entire row if a crash did not occur within these years. This is what I have tried so far with crashes being the data frame:

```
library(sf)

crashes <- st_read("Crash_Analysis_System_(CAS)_data.geojson")

# filtering out crashes not in 2018-2021
crashes <- crashes %>%
  st_filter(crashes %>% filter(crashYear %in% c("2018", "2019", "2020", "2021")))
```

I have executed this, and it looks like it works until I check the updated data frame, it has removed rows as it went from 157,000 to approx 38,000 but when I check it there are still crashes that have occured in the years I don't want there. Am I performing the wrong operation for this kind of thing.

[[image: crashYear collumn after running above code (years don't want show)1]

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is nesting a call to `filter()` from the `dplyr` package within a call to the function `st_filter()` of the `sf` package. `st_filter()` is for filtering by location. This may be geospatial data, but the operation you are doing is a filter on values, not locations. So just remove the `st_filter()` function from your code:

```
library( dplyr )

crashes <- filter(crashes, crashYear %in% c("2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"))
```